# Do data breakpoints in visual studio break only when my program accesses the memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

If I set a data breakpoint in Visual Studio on some memory that my application is using, and that memory is freed again, will the data breakpoint break if some other application uses my program's memory?

If it makes any difference I am working in `C++`.

Answer (score 3):

The data breakpoint is based on the virtual address, so other processes have no access to it, except via something like `WriteProcessMemory`, which (I'm pretty sure) won't trigger the breakpoint either (since, in that case, the writing is done by kernel code, which won't have that breakpoint set).

Comment: Why will the kernal code not have that breakpoint set? I was under the impression that data breakpoints were set on the processor hardware, and always fired.